# Is Ekapeli useful for an adult learner of Finnish?

Tags: electronic-resources, l2-acquisition, finnish

[Ekapeli](http://www.lukimat.fi/lukeminen/materiaalit/ekapeli/mika-ekapeli-on) is an educational game intended for children, especially those with problems with reading and writing Finnish. There are different versions for native Finnish speakers and for immigrants. The game starts by teaching the sounds that the letters make. I don't know what comes after this.

Would the game be useful for adult learners (of Finnish as a second language) who can get past the childish user interface?

I am looking for personal experiences, studies, or something similar, not mere speculation.